# Unable to start an old version of mongodb in ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I installed an old version of mongodb(2.6.9). When I am trying to start the service, using the following command :

```
sudo service mongod start
```

This gives following error :

```
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And running the systemcell command produces following output :

```
sudo systemctl status mongod.service

● mongod.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongod; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-02-20 16:25:20 IST; 12s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4483 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit mongod[4483]: Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit mongod[4483]: utility, e.g. service mongod start
Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit mongod[4483]: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/up
Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit mongod[4483]: Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit mongod[4483]: Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mongod
Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit mongod[4483]: start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upst
Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit systemd[1]: mongod.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit systemd[1]: Failed to start mongod.service.
Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 20 16:25:20 ankit systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Can someone help me with is?

Comment: Hello, in your logs, we can see `Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8) utility, e.g. service mongod start`. Did you try this ?

Comment: Yes I tried, it gives the same error.
$ service mongod start

Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Did you try to start without using `service` or `systemctl` ? I mean directly with the command `mongod`.

Comment: I run the following command :
service mongod start

Comment: That's my point. Could you please try to `mongod` without `service` ? It should something like `<mongodb_path>/bin/mongod --dbpath <path_to_db> ...`